# Firebase update storage based on third party API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a proof of concept using firebase and I was wondering if it would be possible to use firebase as a primary cache and get the data from a third party API to then add the data to storage and send to the user.

For example, get movie data for Guardians of the Galaxy, if it exists in local storage return that otherwise go to third party movie API and cache that info for x time. And return that to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very possible. Look at what [Hacker News did with their API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API), which is effectively treat the Firebase Realtime Database as a read-only cache.